# How to enable caching for Selenium's webdriver Firefox?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

Every time I run`webdriver.Firefox.get('someurl)`code, A new Firefox driver is shown and it doesn't cache any webpage that it loads. I want to make Selenium to tell every Firefox that get loaded to cache webpages so for future uses, they don't have to load every webpage from the beginning. How do I do that?

```
def setup(self):
        print 'running fp'
        self.path = r'path to my profile folder'
        self.profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(self.path)
        self.web = webdriver.Firefox(self.profile)
        self.cache = self.web.application_cache
```

Answer (score 3):

How about creating a new Firefox *profile* with appropriate cache settings and then use it  with `Selenium`?

Take a look at this: http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/

And then in your `Python` script:

```
from selenium import webdriver

firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('path_to_your_profile')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile)
cache = browser.application_cache
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. The browser still loads the same webpage from the beginning  and doesn't utilize cache. I will update my post for sample code.

Comment: How exactly are you checking that the page is not loaded from cache? Can you find your content cached when you paste `about:cache` to the Firefox address bar? Doesn't your site prohibit cache (`<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">`)?

Comment: I checked via a bandwidth monitor software. Say if for a page it takes 7 mb, after applying those setting to Selenium it takes 7 mb to load the page again.Please help I'm so frustrated,thanks.By they way,the site doesn't prohibit cache as I look into it's source code based on what you have said.

I just want the Selenium webdriver's Firefox behave and act like the ordinary Firefox I use for browsing,not a different webdriver specialized by Selenium.